# C#: Как прервать фоновый поток из основного?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Добрый день.

Занимаюсь самообразованием, и задумался над вопросом.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно **прервать фоновый поток из основного**, при этом не используя никакие глобальные переменные и пр. ?
Я знаю про CancellationToken, а есть еще другие способы?

Comment: Thread.Abort https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Его не рекомендуют использовать же!

Comment: Умирать - так с музыкой))) это правильный способ "прервать". Иначе создавайте volative - флаг, например isWork, тестируйте флаг внутри потока, и если он включён - сами выходите с потока. Что-то вроде while (isWork) { working(); }

Comment: А все остальные методы сводятся к Thread.Abort. CancellationToken - это метод синхронизации между потоками, вместо него можно применить volative, а суть та же - тестировать wait переменную.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если правильно, то в обертке потока с некоторой удобной (для целостности обрабатываемых данных) периодичностью проверять некий флаг необходимости прерывания и завершать его по-хорошему.

Comment: Похоже что это единственный способ.
Спасибо

Comment: @LeonardBertone Это единственно правильный способ. Потому что никто, кроме самого потока не должен знать о том, чем он занимается => и как его корректно завершить. Но ему можно "намекнуть" о такой необходимости. Как это реализовать - от публичного свойства до коллбека или события, суть будет одна.

Comment: Только не забудьте пометить такой флаг как `volatile`, иначе есть вероятность, что поток никогда не завершится.

Answer (score 0):

Применяют еще один костыль в исключительных случаях: создают новый домен в приложении, запускают в нем фоновую задачу и при отмене просто убивают этот домен. Что-то типа Thread.Abort, но разрешенный

Comment: При выгрузке домена должны завершиться все выполняющиеся в нём потоки. Если они "не захотят" выгружаться, то проблемы, по сути, те же самые, что и при `Thread.Abort` без домена.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: А интересно, обязательно ли thread принадлежит конкретному AppDomain'у? Если один домен делает вызов в другой, то в каком потоке отрабатывает код?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну это не совсем так. при выгрузке домена освобождение ресурсов будет производить ОС, а не рантайм. Это как создать процесс и убить его, что не есть `Thread.Abort`